# Git pull contents of a folder from a repository

Tags: git, git-checkout, pull, sparse-checkout

I have been trying this with no success.

I have a git repository that contains 3 folders. Lets say:

Folder A
Folder B
Folder C

I want to be able to pull just the contents of folder B to a webserver for example.

I just want to somehow init a git repo on the www folder for example and do some magic and have the files in Folder B pulled to this particular folder.

Doing a sparse-checkout on folder B creates folder B in my www folder. I just need the contents of it.

Is this even posible with Git ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Answer (score 2):

You can try a sparse checkout in order to load only the folder B.

```
git init <repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add -f origin <url>
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "Folder/B/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

See "[Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/6309)"

Since a sparse checkout does create a folder, you need to checkout it somewhere else, and make sure `www` is symlinked to that folder.

Comment: Doing this creates the Folder B folder (ex www/Folder B/~files) I only want the contents of folder B to be pulled (www/~files).

Comment: @MariusIlie then checkout it somewhere else, and set www as a symlink to folder B